# Http get service in angular 2

Tags: angular, spring-boot

I am trying to fetch data from a Spring boot ReST Micro service which gives me data ( username and password) in JSON format 
( [{"username":"Mark","password":"mark123"}] ) through its endpoint "http://localhost:8080/checkUsers"

I created a simple application in angular 2 with basic.service.ts file which fetches data through my RestAPI end point

I am unable to see the data in my console and I am getting this below error in my console

"Failed to load http://localhost:8080/checkUsers: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access."

Below shown is my code

### app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BasicService } from './basic.service';


@NgModule({

  declarations  : [ AppComponent ],
  imports       : [BrowserModule,HttpModule,FormsModule ],
  providers     : [BasicService],
  bootstrap     : [AppComponent]

})

export class AppModule { }
```

### app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { BasicService } from './basic.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: '<h1>{{ title }}</h1>'

})
export class AppComponent {
  title :string;

  constructor(private MyService: BasicService){
        this.title="Angular Service";

        this.MyService.GetPosts()
        .subscribe(posts => {console.log(posts)});
  }
}
```

Here is my service

### basic.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class BasicService {

  constructor(private http:Http) { }

    GetPosts(){
            return this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/checkUsers')
            .map(result => result.json());
    }
}
```

Can anybody please help to solve this issue.

Comment: Have you enabled CORS in your restful service?

Comment: how can we do that ?

Comment: Try to install any browser CORS plugin and enable CORS. @Heena